# Should I put my systemd [Install] section in my .path file or my .service file?

Tags: systemd, services, startup

Configuring systemd to redeploy my service when I commit a new source .jar file, I have a path file that goes along with the service and uses a `PathChanged` directive. I read somewhere that the install section should be in the path file, not the service file, but I notice this makes "systemctl enable MYAPP" impossible. On a server reboot will my app start properly if the Install is just in the .path file? Are there other concerns I should be aware of?

```
# myapp.path
[Unit]
Wants=myapp.service

[Path]
PathChanged=/srv/webapps/myapp/myapp.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `[Install]` section in `myapp.path`.  Then `systemctl enable myapp.path`.

### Why shouldn't it go in `myapp.service`?

If you put the `[Install]` section in `myapp.service`, then the service will be started as soon as `multi-user.target` is raised.  You probably don't want this.  You want `myapp.service` to be started only when `myapp.path` triggers it.

### Why should it go in `myapp.path`?

`myapp.path` triggers `myapp.service`.  Therefore `myapp.path` needs to be started if you want it to do anything.  If you want it to start watching that path as soon as the system starts, then adding an install section is the solution.

### Why didn't `systemctl enable myapp` work?

If you don't specify an extension, `.service` is assumed.  Therefore `systemctl enable myapp` is identical to `systemctl enable myapp.service`.  Since there is no `[Install]` section in `myapp.service`, it failed to enable.  `systemctl enable myapp.path` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Your answer works for enabling with `systemctl enable myapp.path`. But will this cause the program service with which it is associated to actually start at system startup, or will it wait for something new to touch the watched file?

Comment: The `*.service` file will only run if that file changes after the `*.path` file starts.  If you create/modify that file on startup and you don't want the service to be activated, then you'll want to add an `After=` field in your `path` file listing the unit which creates/modifies the file.

Comment: In this case, I DO want it at system startup, so that any server reboots don't shut it down indefinitely. But I also want it to restart whenever the file is changed. In other words, after restarts and at redeployment time. How to do both?